# Pandas: Bar-Plot with two bars from repetitive x-column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a slightly odd csv file where the month column is repeated as such. My goal is to create a bar graph where each month has two columns of y (from both a and b). I have tried to approach this by separating the data frame into two - a only and b only - but the repetition of the month column gets in the way. Fairly new to Python and Pandas so perhaps there is a function I'm not aware of? Any help is appreciated.

```
month   cond. y   

Jan     a     4    
Jan     b     8     
Feb     a     2     
Feb     b     9       
March   a     3   
March   b     7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the most common way to approach this problem is to reshape the long-form data to wide-form via [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'March', 'March'],
    'cond.': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'y': [4, 8, 2, 9, 3, 7]
})

df.pivot(index='month', columns='cond.', values='y').plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1]

---

There is a noticeable issue in that the x-axis columns appear out of order as they are alphabetically ordered and not ordered by Date. One option would be to [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) before plotting. There would be more options if the month column was regular, but since it contains both full month names and abbreviations manually reindexing is likely the best option.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'March', 'March'],
    'cond.': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'y': [4, 8, 2, 9, 3, 7]
})

(
    df.pivot(index='month', columns='cond.', values='y')
        .reindex(['Jan', 'Feb', 'March'])  # Re-order so they appear correctly on x-axis
        .plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 2 reindex]

---

[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) is highly popular in solving these types of questions as the `hue` argument allows the reshaping step to be avoided. Additionally `x` will be in order of appearance in the frame so `reindex` is also unnecessary (assuming the data appears in the correct order in the source DataFrame)

[`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme()  # (optional) Use seaborn theme
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'March', 'March'],
    'cond.': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
    'y': [4, 8, 2, 9, 3, 7]
})

sns.barplot(data=df, x='month', y='y', hue='cond.')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 3 seaborn]

Answer (score 0):

Using the hue attribute to categorize also works

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df,x='Month',y='y',hue='Cond')
```

[result_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muQAx.png)